# Jenkins stage view in progress job time not shown

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins stage view and when a job is in progress the time on the step is not shown, after playing with the CSS in chrome I managed to remove the overlay blue bar and the time is there.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Can I make the time to show over the blue bar?

Answer (score 1):

See this 3 year old defect [JENKINS-46209](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-46209)

You could use the following script to make it work. Kind of.

```js
const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
styleElement.innerHTML = '.progress {background:transparent !important;} .progress-bar {opacity:0.8;}';
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(styleElement);
```

I didn't come up with this script; I came across it a while ago and created a scriptlet for my own use.

Edit:
I found a Chrome extension called - [Blue Ocean Description HTMLify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blue-ocean-description-ht/maahpenodjcdhodbonmdkfgnceddigae) by @jrjurman and submitted [pull request #3](https://github.com/JRJurman/blue-ocean-description-htmlify-chrome-extension/pull/3) to fix this issue.

Please note that it might not work in your case as that extension is hardcoded to work on URL that have "/blue/" in them (Blue Ocean theme); however, you can do a local installation per the [instructions](https://github.com/JRJurman/blue-ocean-description-htmlify-chrome-extension) and update the manifest to include the URLs you would like.

Comment: How can I implement this script in Jenkins?

Comment: Not in Jenkins unless Jenkins developers fix it. I updated the answer to include an extension that **may** work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but adding my two cents. If you're using the  Jenkins Simple Theme plugin, you can fix this by going to Configure System -> Theme -> Extra CSS and adding the following:

```
div[class*=duration] { z-index: 10 }
```